# Unicodedata works in terminal but not on .py

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

I am trying to remove the accents from Spanish words. If I do

```
import unicodedata

name="Tecnología"
uname=unicode(name, "utf-8")
nameclean=unicodedata.normalize(u"NFKD", uname).encode("ascii", erros="ignore")
```

In the terminal version of python it works and returns "Tecnologia", but inside the script `.py` it doesn't. I don't get it. The error I receive is

```
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

specifically for the first part of the command `unicodedata.normalize(u"NFKD", uname)`. I have made sure I am using the same sentence for both cases and I split the commands to know exactly where is the problem.

I am running python 2.7.5 and unicodedata2 12.0.0 (`pip install` didn't find `unicodedata`, also have `unicode` and `Unicode` installed)

---

Edit:

This is how the terminal looks like. Everything works fine, but when used inside a `.py` it returns the error I mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, it was that! I feel so stupid! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reported exception is raised when Python is asked to decode a `unicode` instance to unicode.

```
>>> name = u"Tecnología"
>>> uname = unicode(name, "utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```